# iOS App Crash in unknown module-mdDoRequest mdlExchange mdlRemoteExec

Tags: ios, crash

The crash tools report a weird crash of my app.

It crashed at `MDOSWebViewDelegate`. 
After listed all the symbols of binary with command `nm -a myApp`, 
and still can't locate it from the crash stack.

I don't even know what features of these modules, it seems this module is from an `System framework`.
(`mdDoRequest mdlExchange mdlRemoteExec`)

Following is the crash stack.

```
crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6e2e6483

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x37305f46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  MyApp                       0x00d59ca3 mdDoRequest (MDOSWebViewDelegate.m:129)
2  MyApp                       0x00d5dafb mdlExchange (lang.c:57)
3  MyApp                       0x00d5df4f mdlRemoteExec (lang.c:110)
4  MyApp                       0x00d592e5 forwardInvocation (MDOSProxy.m:213)
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2943d62f ___forwarding___ + 354
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2936f008 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
7  CoreFoundation                 0x293f2e31 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x2934e6cd _CFXNotificationPost + 1784
9  Foundation                     0x2a0a4dd9 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
10 UIKit                          0x2cbbba65 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDectivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 980
11 UIKit                          0x2cbc2d8d __88-[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 76
12 UIKit                          0x2cbc2d39 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 360
13 UIKit                          0x2cbb7ef3 -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 478
14 FrontBoardServices             0x2fd83169 __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 40
15 FrontBoardServices             0x2fd920a9 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 12
16 CoreFoundation                 0x29400fe5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
17 CoreFoundation                 0x294002a9 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 216
18 CoreFoundation                 0x293fede3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1714
19 CoreFoundation                 0x2934c3b1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
20 CoreFoundation                 0x2934c1c3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21 GraphicsServices               0x30939201 GSEventRunModal + 136
22 UIKit                          0x2c9b643d UIApplicationMain + 1440
23 MyApp                       0x0003696f main (main.m:19)
```

Any suggestion?